# Polygon region of interest (ROI)

Tags: opencv

Imagine you are filming a large room with your webcam and there is a fenced zigzag queue filling with people in that room. Now you want to apply computationally intensive operations to the camera image and to keep the input image data as small as possible, you want to mark the "Region of Interest" as polygon, which corresponds to the queue, in order to exclude all unnecessary image areas. Many functions, such as the Tracking API, always expect a cv::Rect2d. If my ROI is not square, but a polygon with more than 4 points, do I have to convert it into multiple rectangles (cv::Rect2d) and then apply the operations to each individual rectangle, or is there another way? 
Or would it already help if I cut out the ROI with a mask and add black dots to the rest of the image to save computing time?

Comment: Profile and measure performance before trying cumbersome solutions

Comment: @Miki: I already have. It makes no sense to perform compute-intensive operations such as face detection (deep neural network) in image areas where no one is ever present. In general, one tries to keep the resolution as low as possible in order to reduce the CPU/GPU load, but the accuracy suffers from this. Therefore it makes sense to search only the image sections in higher resolution, in which you will then also find people.